# Jython photo editing in real time

Tags: jython

I am taking an intro to programming class which focuses on Jython, and I am having difficulty completing our current assignment. the program should ask the user to select a picture from their files, and "posterize" the image. This isn't where my issue arises, but here is what i have so far...
def main():

```
file = pickAFile()

pic = makePicture(file)

for p in getPixels(pic):

red = getRed(p)
green = getGreen(p)
blue = getBlue(p)

if (red < 128):
  setRed(p, 0)
else:
  setRed(p, 255)

if (green < 128):
  setGreen(p, 0)
else:
  setGreen(p, 255)

if (blue < 128):
  setBlue(p, 0)
else:
  setBlue(p, 255)
```

show(pic)
  return(pic)

This completes the first step of the project without issue. The next step is where I have problems.

We have to modify the program to complete the editing in "real-time". I am assuming that we have to show the original picture, have it edited on screen to the final "posterized" image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues reading your code due to the lack of indentation. Python (or in this case, the Java implementation of Python, Jython) runs its entire syntax off of indentation. Therefore, I can't really read your code to help you much right now. I know what to do with your code, I just need to see the code indented.